# double integration gives error object y not found

Tags: r, cran, integrate

I am trying to do this integration

[image]

I am trying this code

```
integrand_inner <- function(x, a, b) {(a * x^2 + b * y *x)*y}

integrand_outer <- Vectorize(
  function(y, a, b){
    integrate(integrand_inner,
              (bo - b)*y/(a-ao),
              1,
              a=a,
              b=b)$value
  }
)

revenue <- function(a){
  b <- sqrt(1-a^2)
  
  return(integrate(integrand_outer, 0, 1, a = a, b=b))
}
```

But I get the error

```
Error in f(x, ...) : object 'y' not found
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Needed to add y as an argument to the function and pass it on.

```
integrand_inner <- function(x,y, a, b) {(a * x^2 + b * y *x)*y}

integrand_outer <- Vectorize(
  function(y, a, b){
    integrate(integrand_inner,
              (bo - b)*y/(a-ao),
              1,
              a=a,
              b=b,
              y=y)$value
  }
)

revenue <- function(a){
  b <- sqrt(1-a^2)
  
  return(integrate(integrand_outer, 0, 1, a = a, b=b))
}
```